# How do save the result of pyresample processing as GeoTIFF file？

Tags: python, geoprocessing, remote-sensing

To warp image to GeoTIFF using GCPs method, I used the pyresample package. As the result, I did not find any example to save this result as a GeoTIFF file.

```
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
from pyresample import image, geometry,save_quicklook
file="C:/Users/TLQ/Desktop/11/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.hdf"
f1 = SD(file, SDC.READ)
lat = f1.select('Latitude')
latitude = lat[:,:]
lon = f1.select('Longitude')
longitude = lon[:,:]
b1 = f1.select('BAND31')
AOP = b1[:,:]
swath_def = geometry.SwathDefinition(lons=longitude, lats=latitude)
swath_con = image.ImageContainerNearest(AOP, swath_def, radius_of_influence=10000)
```

Comment: What does `swath_con.image_data` return? A numpy array?

Comment: No, it is <class 'pyresample.image.ImageContainerNearest'>

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar but not exactly the same problem, here is my solution.

```py
import os
import h5py
import numpy
import rasterio
import pyresample
import subprocess
from IPython.display import Image
#%% read data
filename = "C:/Datasets/FY3D-MWRI/FY3D_MWRIA_GBAL_L1_20220301_0423_010KM_MS.HDF"
f_obj = h5py.File(filename)

dem_arr = f_obj["Calibration/DEM"][:]
lat_arr = f_obj["Geolocation/Latitude"][:]
lon_arr = f_obj["Geolocation/Longitude"][:]

#%% Resample to equal lat/lon grid
# resolution can be calculated by converting 1 arc second to approximately 30m
# area_extent: (lower_left_x, lower_left_y, upper_right_x, upper_right_y)
area_def = pyresample.create_area_def(
    units="degrees",
    resolution=0.09259,
    area_id="my_area",
    area_extent=[73, 10, 140, 55],
    projection={"proj": "longlat", "datum": "WGS84"},
    description="China 10kmx10km degree lat-lon grid",

)

swath_def = pyresample.geometry.SwathDefinition(lons=lon_arr, lats=lat_arr)

result = pyresample.kd_tree.resample_nearest(
    swath_def, dem_arr, area_def, fill_value=9999, radius_of_influence=10000)

#%% output to tiff
output_filename=  "./hello.tif"
outds = rasterio.open("hello.tif",
                      mode="w",
                      count=1,
                      nodata=9999,
                      driver="GTiff",
                      dtype=numpy.int16,
                      crs='+proj=latlong',
                      width=result.shape[1],
                      height=result.shape[0],
                      transform=[0.09259, 0, 73, 0, -0.09259, 55],
                      )
outds.write(result, 1)
outds.close()
```

The results can be plotted using GMT

[image: plot the tif]